# Reference a projected/selected column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I project a column in my select statement. ("project" in the relational algebra sense.) With the goal of reducing code duplication, is there a way to reference that projected column in my where clause? Or is there a better way to do that?

Example:

```
select
  (A.Column + A.Column2) * 8 'Column'
from A
where
  (A.Column + A.Column2) * 8 < 1000
```

Basically, what I'm asking, if we think of columns as being "namespaced" by table (where A is a namespace and A.Column is the Column in the A namespace), is: is there a way to refer to the namespace for the ephemeral table we're currently selecting in the where clause of that table itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is to use cte, common table expression.

```
with cte as(
  select (A.Column + A.Column2) * 8 as [Column] from A
)
Select * from cte
Where [Column] < 1000
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it;

```
 select * from 
 (
 select (A.Column + A.Column2) * 8 as Col from A
 ) tmp 
 where Col<1000
```

Comment: You're not wrong, but eww... :)

I'm guessing it's probably not possible, since (IIRC from DB class), if you conceptualize queries as have an order of operations, the selection/projection stage is last.